# How to install GRASS on Linux Mint?

Tags: grass-gis, linux, linux-mint

I'm trying to figure out an error in GRASS network analysis for several days now. I started to suspect that it has something to do with my OS, namely Windows 7. Hence I installed Linux-Mint 14 (Nadia) on my computer. I would like to run GRASS 6.4 (or latest) on Linux to test the function, yet can't figure out how to do so.

Can someone help me with it? Or direct me to some where on the web where it is explained?

Comment: http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/grass - Then click install.  Looks like Mint manages everything from there.

Comment: @JayLaura You might want to post that as an answer ;-)

Comment: @R.K. Done - it just felt like fishing for votes...

Comment: What is? Isn't that how we reward good answers around here?

Comment: thanks for all helpful and detailed answers. I hope it will also solve my net analysis problem in grass

Comment: Just for completeness, the ubuntugis unstable ppa also maintains a recent version of GRASS for ubuntu LTR versions. Unfortuantely, Linux Mint 14 is not supported anymore, but for Linux Mint 13 (precise), 17.x (trusty) and 18.x (xenial) it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that mint is able to handle package installation via a web embeddable trigger.

Navigate to [community.linuxmint.com/software/view/grass](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/grass) and click install.

Looks like Mint manages everything from there.

Comment: Hope the packagers will update to the current stable version soon...

Comment: ...unless there are unmet dependencies/held/broken packages, then you can expect to while away a few hours trying to get the blasted thing to install.

Answer (score 6):

You open your package manager. Type grass. Hit the install button. It should be able to identify any dependencies you may not have and install those as well. A package manager usually comes with a Linux installation. Some are better than others. I like synaptic.

Answer (score 6):

Package management in Mint Linux is based on apt: http://wiki.debian.org/Apt, which means that the following, typed into your terminal, should install GRASS:

sudo apt-get install grass

Once the package is installed, you should be able to launch it by typing

grass

into your terminal.

This will get you the latest stable version of GRASS.  If you want something newer, you'll have to download and compile the source code: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/DownloadSource; however, that is generally only recommended for advanced users who are willing to accept the tradeoff of potential instability & bugs to try out the latest and greatest version.